# django deployment on heliohost

Tags: django, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a small django app on heliohost following the instructions in this post [How to deploy a Django site using a different version of Django on Heliohost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080657/how-to-deploy-a-django-site-using-a-different-version-of-django-on-heilohost) and also the official [ones](http://www.heliohost.org/home/features/languages/python). But when I try to browse the site I only get the index of my public_html folder. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but if you still trying django on heliohost, try cookiecutter template for heliohost.

```
$ pip install cookiecutter
$ cookiecutter https://github.com/rahul-gj/cookiecutter-helio.git
  project_name [mysite]: ---> Type your project name here.
  helio_user [user_name]: ---> your heliohost username.
```

The folder with project name will be created in your working directory.
Paste the content of the folder (folder + manage.py file) on heliohost public_html directory.

go to yourusername.heliohost.org/yourproject

You should see something like this:
https://krydos.heliohost.org/djangotest/

Explore the django on heliohost.

Comment: How will the python modules be installed there ?

Comment: I am talking about local installation. then there will be folder created locally. You need to put that in public_html directory. Are you on tommy?

Comment: I completed my project in my PC. Now I want to upload it. How can I install the modules in online server in heliohost?